# How to improve the performance of a merge operation with an incremental DeltaLake table?

Tags: python, apache-spark, delta-lake

I am specifically looking to optimize performance by updating and inserting data to a DeltaLake base table, with about 4 trillion records.

Environment:

- Spark 3.0.0
- DeltaLake 0.7.0

In context this is about making an incremental table via DeltaLake, I'll summarize this in steps to be more detailed:

1. Creation of the base table (delta)
2. Obtaining periodic data
3. Add the data to the base table

Steps 1 and 2 have already been done, but when adding the data the performance is notoriously slow, for example adding a 9GB CSV takes about 6 hours, this mainly because delta needs to rewrite the data for each update, it also needs "read" all data from the database.

This table is also partitioned (`PARTITIONED BY`) and stored in the cluster's GDFS (HDFS) to ensure that the spark nodes can perform the operations.

The fields of the base table:

| Name | Type | Cardinality | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID | `int` | 10000 | Identifier |
| TYPE | `string` | 30 |  |
| LOCAL_DATE | `date` |  | Local date of the record |
| DATE_UTC | `date` |  | UTC date of registration |
| VALUE | `int` |  | Registry value |
| YEAR | `int` | 4 | Calculated column |
| MONTH | `int` | 12 | Calculated column |
| DAY | `int` | 31 | Calculated column |

As the general search is by time, it was decided to partition by the `LOCAL_DATE` column in `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DAY`, partitioning by the ID and `LOCAL_DATE` columns was ruled out due to its high level of cardinality, (which for performance purposes is worse), it was added finally `TYPE`, being as follows:

```py
spark.sql(f"""
    CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE  {TABLE_NAME} (
        ID INT, 
        FECHA_LOCAL TIMESTAMP,
        FECHA_UTC TIMESTAMP,
        TIPO STRING, 
        VALUE DOUBLE,
        YEAR INT,
        MONTH INT, 
        DAY INT )
    USING DELTA
    PARTITIONED BY (YEAR , MONTH , DAY, TIPO)
    LOCATION '{location}'
""")
```

From now on, the incrementality is given by periodically adding these csv files of approximately 9GB every 5 days. Currently the `MERGE` operation is as follows:

```py
spark.sql(f"""
    MERGE INTO {BASE_TABLE_NAME}
    USING {INCREMENTAL_TABLE_NAME} ON 
        --partitioned cols
        {BASE_TABLE_NAME}.YEAR        = {INCREMENTAL_TABLE_NAME}.YEAR AND
        {BASE_TABLE_NAME}.MONTH       = {INCREMENTAL_TABLE_NAME}.MONTH AND  
        {BASE_TABLE_NAME}.DAY         = {INCREMENTAL_TABLE_NAME}.DAY AND 
        {BASE_TABLE_NAME}.TIPO        = {INCREMENTAL_TABLE_NAME}.TIPO AND 
        {BASE_TABLE_NAME}.FECHA_LOCAL = {INCREMENTAL_TABLE_NAME}.FECHA_LOCAL AND 
        {BASE_TABLE_NAME}.ID          = {INCREMENTAL_TABLE_NAME}.ID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
        SET {BASE_TABLE_NAME}.VALUE = {INCREMENTAL_TABLE_NAME}.VALUE,
            {BASE_TABLE_NAME}.TIPO  = {INCREMENTAL_TABLE_NAME}.TIPO
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
    """)
```

Some facts to consider:

- The time of this MERGE operation is 6 hours
- The base table was created from 230GB CSV data (55GB now in delta!)
- The spark application configuration is in cluster mode with the following parameters
- The infra consists of 3 nodes, 32 cores and 250GB RAM each, although it takes up less for security than the other existing applications approximately -50% of resources.

Spark app:

```py
mode = 'spark://spark-master:7077'
# mode = 'local [*]'
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .master(mode)
    .appName("SparkApp")
    .config('spark.cores.max', '45')
    .config('spark.executor.cores', '5')
    .config('spark.executor.memory', '11g')
    .config('spark.driver.memory', '120g')
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "200") # 200 only for 200GB delta table reads
    .config("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "0.8")
    # DeltaLake configs
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:0.7.0")
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
    # Delta optimization
    .config("spark.databricks.delta.optimizeWrite.enabled", "true")
    .config("spark.databricks.delta.retentionDurationCheck.enabled", "false")
    .getOrCreate()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I choose to share this answer so that you can take advantage of some tips.

Delta recommends using all partitioned columns, in this way the final data search is less, given by the effect of "pruning"

So it is necessary to identify all the cases where the merge can update the data, for this
A query is made on the incremental data to generate a dictionary of this type:

```
filter_columns = spark.sql (f "" "
SELECT
    YEAR,
    MONTH,
    DAY,
    COLLECT_LIST (DISTINCT TYPE) AS TYPES
Incremental FROM
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH, DAY
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
"" ") .toPandas ()
```

With this df it is possible to generate the conditions where the merge must update / insert:

[! [df grouped by year, month, day, type] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9fhK.png)] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9fhK.png)

Then it generated a string called "final_cond" like this:

```
dic = filter_columns.groupby (['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY']) ['TYPE']. apply (lambda grp: list (grp.value_counts (). index)). to_dict ()
final_cond = ''
index = 0
for key, value in dic.items ():
    cond = ''
    year = key [0]
    month = key [1]
    day = key [2]
    variables = ','. join (["'" + str (x) + "'" for x in value [0]])
    or_cond = '' if index + 1 == len (dic) else '\ nOR \ n'
    
    cond = f "" "({BASE_TABLE_NAME} .YEAR == {year} AND {BASE_TABLE_NAME} .MONTH == {month} AND {BASE_TABLE_NAME} .DAY == {day} AND {BASE_TABLE_NAME}. TYPE IN ({variables} )) "" "
      
    final_cond = final_cond + cond + f '{or_cond}'
    index + = 1
    #break
    
print (final_cond)
```

[! [string condition] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q9zi.png)]

Finally we add these conditions to the MERGE:

```
...
WHEN MATCHED AND ({final_cond}) THEN
...
```

This simple "filter" reduced the merge time for large operations